# Google Maps for Rails - Center on marker always max zoomed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am using Google maps for rails and I have everything setup properly but I can't seem to figure out how to set the default zoom number. I tried setting it in gmaps4rails.base.js.coffee here:

```
@default_map_options = 
      id: 'map'
      draggable: true
      detect_location: false  # should the browser attempt to use geolocation detection features of HTML5?
      center_on_user: false   # centers map on the location detected through the browser
      center_latitude: 0
      center_longitude: 0 
      zoom: 7
      maxZoom: null
      minZoom: null
      auto_adjust : true      # adjust the map to the markers if set to true
      auto_zoom: true         # zoom given by auto-adjust
      bounds: []              # adjust map to these limits. Should be [{"lat": , "lng": }]    
      raw: {}                  # raw json to pass additional options
```

but i dont think that worked properly. Is there a way to add the zoom number when creating the map:

```
<%= gmaps(:markers => {:data => @json, 
                      :options => {:raw => '{ animation: google.maps.Animation }' } },
                      :map_options => { :raw => '{ disableDefaultUI: false, 
                                                   scrollwheel: true }' }) %>
```

nothing I do seems to do anything, it is always zoomed all the way in. thanks!

Comment: try auto-zoom : false in your options

Comment: i've tried that. it didn't change anything. i tried restarting my server too. these options don't seem to be making any changes

Comment: don't really understand: do you have markers on the map? none, one or many?

Comment: please provide more details if you expect an answer!

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Can you provide your solution?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, which works (note that i use `haml`. Use `<%= %>` for `erb`):

```
= gmaps("map_options" => { "detect_location" => true, "center_on_user" => true, "auto_zoom" => false, "zoom" => 16},"markers" => { "data" => @json })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set :auto_zoom => false, :zoom => value

```
<%= gmaps(:markers => {:data => @json, 
                  :options => {:raw => '{ animation: google.maps.Animation }' } },
                  :map_options => { :raw => '{ disableDefaultUI: false, 
                                               scrollwheel: true,
                                               auto_zoom => false,
                                               zoom => 10 }' }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish but my challenge was that with auto zoom it would zoom in so far that the perspective was all wrong.  My solution was to change the max zoom value in the base coffee script.  Snippet below.  Note the auto remains true.

```
  center_longitude: 0
  zoom: 7
  maxZoom: 18
  minZoom: null
  auto_adjust : true      # adjust the map to the markers if set to true
  auto_zoom: true         # zoom given by auto-adjust
  bounds: []              # adjust map to these limits. Should be [{"lat": , "lng": }]
  raw: {}                  # raw json to pass additional options
```

The other haml solution mention in the answers also works for a single page.